# Windows UI Automation: thread blocking when adding event handlers

Tags: c#, multithreading, ui-automation, uia

I am writing a C# program, which uses the UI Automation via Com interop. However, I am having a problem adding/removing an event handler from within another event handler:

My program starts up a new MTA thread, and on that thread, calls AddFocusChangedEventHandler().

I want to monitor for property changes on the focused element. So within the focus-changed handler, I call RemovePropertyChangedEventHandler() on the previously focused element, and AddPropertyChangedEventHandler() on the newly focused element.

However, I find that after about two focus changes, I stop getting either focus-changed, or property-changed, events. My hunch is that something is blocking the background thread.

If I remove the property-changed code, then just the focus tracking works just as expected.

I'm not sure if this is pertenant - but the documentation states that event handlers should be added/removed on the same thread. Since I'm calling AddPropertyChangedEventHandler() in one focus-changed event, and RemovePropertyChangedEventHandler() in another focus-changed event, it's possible that the two calls are being executed on different threads. However, I doubt this to be the case - and even if it were, it shouldn't exhibit the blocking behavior I see. Just mentioning it here for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

There may be multiple problems here. But it's worth noting that after you RemovePropertyChangedEventHandler, you may still get some more events if there are multiple events on the same item (you'll for example get multiple child_added structure changed events if there are multiple children added to an item, it may be similar with multiple properties changing - but not sure). So, if you get multiple events, your code will be called multiple times, probably messing things up.

Another issue is, as you've pointed, you shouldn't subscribe / unsubscribe to events from different threads. But I think this is relevant when there's a chance that these actions are not synchronized - if you're subscribing and unsubscribing to different events (likely in your case) then things will get messy - I'll hazard to say that if you do the subs/unsubs in sequence by some lock mechanism then it should be fine.